# Div tag doesn't show any result

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

In my code after sending a request to a JSP page using an AJAX call, it does not show the result in the `<div>` tag. Id of my `<div>` tag is "div1". Control is passed to the JSP page. After processing the JSP page, the value in `responseText` is not displayed in the `<div>` tag. I don't understand the reason. I am hereby attaching the code ... and also can i add events to the  tags on "new.jsp" file?

```
<%-- 
Document   : Databases
Created on : Nov 10, 2014, 3:08:01 PM
Author     : user
--%>

   <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
  <%@page import="java.sql.DatabaseMetaData"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
   <%@page import="querywork.DBConnection"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
  <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
  <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script language="javascript"   type="text/javascript">

        try
        {

            function create(str)
            { 
                var xmlHttp 


                xmlHttp=CreateXmlHttpObject()
                if (xmlHttp==null)
                {
                    alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
                    return
                } 

                var url="new.jsp"
                url=url+"?dbname="+str

                url=url+"&sid="+Math.random()
                //  out.print(url)
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
                xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
                xmlHttp.send()

            }
            function stateChanged() 
            { 
                if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
                { 
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText 
                } 
            } 
            function CreateXmlHttpObject()
            { 
                var objXMLHttp=null
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject)
                {
                    objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                }
                return objXMLHttp
            }
        }
        catch(err)
        {}
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

        <h2>Databases</h2>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield" value="Database Name" id="dbname" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="CREATE" onClick="create(textfield.value)"/>

        </label>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>



        <%
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "root", "");

                DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();

                ResultSet ctlgs = dbmd.getCatalogs();

        %>


        <table border="1" cellpadding ="2"cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    Database Name
                </td>

            </tr>
            <%
                while (ctlgs.next()) {
            %>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="ch" type="checkbox" value="" id="" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=ctlgs.getString(1)%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%}
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.println(e);
                }%>
        </table>
        <a href="Delete.jsp">Drop</a>
        <br></br>
        <div id="div1">ffff</div>
    </form>


</body>
```

new.jsp

```
<%-- 
Document   : new
Created on : Nov 11, 2014, 12:41:34 PM
Author     : user
--%>

  <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
  <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

    <%@page import="querywork.DBConnection"%>
   <%@page import="javax.faces.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior"%>
     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html>

  <%
try {
    String responseText = new String("");
    boolean flg = false;
    String OptionValue = (String) request.getParameter("dbname");


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("create database " + OptionValue);
    int k = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (k > 0) {
        flg = true;
    } else {
        flg = false;
    }

    responseText += OptionValue;

} catch (Exception e) {
    out.print(e);
}
 %>
```

Comment: What does the console show??

Comment: Console doesn't show any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the issues I've identified:

### Issue 1

You're creating a `responseText` string, but you're not writing it to the output stream, so it will not be present in the response that is sent back to the client.

At the end of your `try` block (in `new.jsp`), after doing

```
responseText += OptionValue;
```

you need to add

```
out.print(responseText);
```

### Issue 2

Your button is of type `submit`, so it submits the form. This means that the page will be reloaded immediately after calling the AJAX request. Add `return false` to your `onclick` handler as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="CREATE"
    onclick="create(textfield.value); return false;"/>
```

Or change your buttom from a `submit` button to a regular button:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="CREATE"
    onclick="create(textfield.value)"/>
```

### Issue 3

You need to declare `var xmlHttp` outside of your `create` method. As it is now, your `stateChanged()` method has no access to your `xmlHttp` variable.

Comment: I have added out.print(responseText) at the end of try block.but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I am new to web app and so i didn't understood the problem.can u explain me with an example?